# Finding the Fourier transform of an equation

Tags: fourier-analysis

[image: Calculate Fourier Transform]

I need to calculate the Fourier transform, but I don't know how to do it. Help me, please!

Comment: Try [`FourierTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html) on [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) or *Mathematica*, if you have it.

Comment: I have already tried :c

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: Fourier transform [1-sin(x)^2/x^2+ (∫(sin(xz)/z)dz from 1 to inf) d(sin(x)/x))/dx, x, n]

Comment: @АртемАртем that's not *Mathematica* code. Are you sure you are on the right forum?

Answer (score 2):

I'll use *Mathematica* to be pragmatic & quick here.

Let's Fourier-transform the three terms separately:

#### first term

```
F1[k_] = FourierTransform[1, x, k]
```

> Sqrt[2π] DiracDelta[k]

#### second term

```
F2[k_] = Assuming[Element[k, Reals], 
  FourierTransform[Sinc[x]^2, x, k] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify]
```

> $$
> \begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} (k+2) & -2\leq k<0 \\
>  -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} (k-2) & 0\leq k\leq 2
> \end{cases}
> $$

#### third term

Let's [interchange the integration with the Fourier transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) without proving that it's legal. First Fourier-transform the integrand,

```
f3[k_, z_] = Assuming[Element[k, Reals] && z >= 1, 
  FourierTransform[Sin[x z]/z Sinc'[x], x, k] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify]
```

> $$
> \begin{cases}
>  -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{2} & k+1=z\land k+z=1 \\
>  \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} (k-z)}{4 z} & (k+1=z\lor k=z+1)\land k+z>1 \\
>  \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} (k-z)}{2 z} & z<k+1\land k<z+1 \\
>  -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} (k+z)}{2 z} & -1<k+z<1 \\
>  -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} (k+z)}{4 z} & (k+z+1=0\lor k+z=1)\land k+1<z
> \end{cases}
> $$

then do the integral over $z$:

```
F3[k_] = Assuming[Element[k, Reals], 
  Integrate[f3[k, z], {z, 1, ∞}] // FullSimplify]
```

> $$
> \begin{cases}
>  -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(k \log \left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right)+2\right) & k\leq -2 \\
>  -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k (\log (1-k)-1) & -2<k\leq 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k (\log (k+1)-1) & 0<k\leq 2 \\
>  \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(k \log \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)-2\right) & \text{True}
> \end{cases}
> $$

#### all terms together

```
F[k_] = Assuming[Element[k, Reals], 
  F1[k] + F2[k] + F3[k] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify]
```

> $$
> \begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{4} \left(4 \sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (k)-\sqrt{2 \pi } k \log \left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right)-2 \sqrt{2 \pi }\right) &
>    k<-2 \\
>  \frac{1}{4} \left(4 \sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (k)+\sqrt{2 \pi } k-\sqrt{2 \pi } k \log \left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right)\right) &
>    k=-2 \\
>  \frac{1}{4} \left(4 \sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (k)+2 \sqrt{2 \pi } k-\sqrt{2 \pi } k \log (1-k)+2 \sqrt{2 \pi }\right) &
>    -2<k<0 \\
>  \frac{1}{4} \left(4 \sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (k)-\sqrt{2 \pi } k \log (1-k)+2 \sqrt{2 \pi }\right) & k=0 \\
>  \frac{1}{4} \left(4 \sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (k)-2 \sqrt{2 \pi } k+\sqrt{2 \pi } k \log (k+1)+2 \sqrt{2 \pi }\right) &
>    0<k\leq 2 \\
>  \frac{1}{4} \left(4 \sqrt{2 \pi } \delta (k)+\sqrt{2 \pi } k \log \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)-2 \sqrt{2 \pi }\right) &
>    \text{True}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Make a plot of the Fourier transform, keeping in mind that we cannot see the Dirac $\delta$-function at the origin:

```
Plot[F[k], {k, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]